# Rails Nokogiri XML Parser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I am a rails newbie and trying to work my way through an nokogiri XML Parser.

I found a lot of helpful stuff but it never came together completely for me. SO I thought I would ask for your help, this is my first stackoverflow question. so here goes:

In my Product model I define as follows

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord 
    def self.xml_parser
        xml_string = open("#{Rails.root}/datafeed.xml").read
        doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_string)
        frothieproducts = doc.xpath('//FeedItems/FeedItem')
        frothieproducts.each do |feeditem|
            product.product_name = feeditem.xpath('Name').text
            product.product_description = feeditem.xpath('Description').text
            product.product_link = feeditem.xpath('Url').text
        end
    end
end
```

Then I run in rails console with Product.xml_parser and get a little => 0

my xml file looks like so and is named datafeed.xml and in the top level

```
<FeedItems>
    <FeedItem>
        <MerchantId>24870</MerchantId>
        <MerchantCampaignName>Froothie</MerchantCampaignName>
        <DateCreated>2016-02-04T18:43:00.787</DateCreated>
        <DateModified>2016-02-04T18:43:00.787</DateModified>
        <SKU>400BLK</SKU>
        <Name>The OPTIMUM 400</Name>
        <Category>The OPTIMUM 400 - Revolutionary Cold Press Juicer (Black)</Category>
        <Description>The OPTIMUM 400 - Revolutionary Cold Press Juicer (Black)</Description>
        <Url>https://t.cfjump.com/13467/p/18074772</Url>
        <OriginalUrl>http://www.froothie.com.au/store/optimum-juicer/optimum-slow-juicer</OriginalUrl>
        <Image>http://c.cfjump.com/Products/24870/18074772.jpg</Image>
        <Image50>http://c.cfjump.com/Products/24870/18074772@50x50.jpg</Image50>
        <Image100>http://c.cfjump.com/Products/24870/18074772@100x100.jpg</Image100>
        <Image120>http://c.cfjump.com/Products/24870/18074772@120x120.jpg</Image120>
        <Image200>http://c.cfjump.com/Products/24870/18074772@200x200.jpg</Image200>
        <Image300>http://c.cfjump.com/Products/24870/18074772@300x300.jpg</Image300>
        <Image400>http://c.cfjump.com/Products/24870/18074772@400x400.jpg</Image400>
        <Price>449</Price>
        <Brand></Brand>
        <Colour>Black</Colour>
        <Currency>AUD</Currency>
        <DeliveryCost></DeliveryCost>
        <DeliveryTime></DeliveryTime>
        <Features></Features>
        <Gender></Gender>
        <Genre></Genre>
        <Keywords></Keywords>
        <ContentRating></ContentRating>
        <ModelNumber></ModelNumber>
        <Platform></Platform>
        <PriceRrp>449</PriceRrp>
        <PriceSale></PriceSale>
        <PromoText></PromoText>
        <Size></Size>
        <StockLevel></StockLevel>
        <SubCategory></SubCategory>
        <Custom1></Custom1>
        <Custom2></Custom2>
        <Custom3></Custom3>
        <Custom4></Custom4>
    </FeedItem>
```

Looking forward to your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parsing code is ok, but you should return array of products. I don't see how you declare `product` variable. 
This code will return an array of products.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord 
    def self.xml_parser
        doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("#{Rails.root}/datafeed.xml"))
        frothieproducts = doc.xpath('//FeedItems/FeedItem')
        frothieproducts.map do |feeditem|
            product = Product.new
            product.product_name = feeditem.xpath('Name').text
            product.product_description = feeditem.xpath('Description').text
            product.product_link = feeditem.xpath('Url').text
            product.save!
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for that, definitely helped things along. I can see it pulled the URL, but nothing else.... it didn't save any products to my db.

Comment: Yes, it's just returning list of product's objects. I've update answer to save product in db. Try it now.

Comment: Alex, you are awesome, best thing to wake up to

Comment: I have labeled this self.xml_parser so that i can hit it from the console. Could I created a second xml_parser for a different file and name it something else and still be able to call it from console?

Comment: Yes, of course. You can create another method (like xml_parser_2) in Product model another method to parse another file. Or you can create separate module and move all parsing code to this file. module ParseProduct; def self.parse_1;.... def self.parse_2;.. ;end